# Angular2: PUT request to Node-Server doesn't work - authentication lost

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, authentication, server

I'm using Angular2 on the client side and a node-express server as my backend. The node-server works as an API-middleware and also as my authentication service. The user-requests must contain a valid JWT token to perform requests on the node-server.

All of my GET functions and other PUT functions are working properly. I wrote a new one, which just should delete an ID on a third-party API, doesn't.

Furthermore, my node-express server sends custom error messages at some points to the client. This comes to my problem, whenever I run my latest PUT-function, my server responds with "No token provided". This happens when the user isn't logged in on the client side.

As I said, all my other functions working. `this.createAuthenticationHeaders();` is necessary to perform valid request on the server side. But it's implemented.

In other words, the authentication gets lost between client and server and I get my own error message: **"No token provided"**.

**Appointment-Detail.Component.ts**

```
cancelAppointment() {
    this.authService.getProfile().subscribe(profile => {
      this.username = profile.user.username; // Set username
      this.email = profile.user.email; // Set e-mail
      if (profile.user.email) {
        this.apiService.cancelUserAppointment(this.id).subscribe(data => {
          console.log(this.id);
          if (!data.success) {
            this.messageClass = 'alert alert-danger'; // Set error bootstrap class
            this.message = data.message; // Set error message
          } else {
            this.messageClass = 'alert alert-success'; // Set success bootstrap class
            this.message = data.message; // Set success message
            // After two seconds, navigate back to blog page
          }
        });
      }
    });
  }
```

**API Service**

```
cancelUserAppointment(id) {
    this.createAuthenticationHeaders();
    console.log('API SERVICE ' + id);
    return this.http
      .put(this.domain + 'api/appointments/' + id + '/cancel', this.options)
      .map(res => res.json());
  }
```

**An API Service functions that works**

```
getCertificatesByUser(email) {
    this.createAuthenticationHeaders();
    return this.http
      .get(this.domain + 'api/user/' + email + '/certificates', this.options)
      .map(res => res.json());
  }
```

**Server route to the third party API**

```
  router.put('/appointments/:id/cancel', (req, res) => {
    console.log('hi');
    var id = req.params.id;
    const url = process.env.acuityUri + '/appointments/' + id + '/cancel';
    console.log(id);
  });
```

**Authentication middleware**

```
router.use((req, res, next) => {
    const token = req.headers['authorization']; // Create token found in headers
    // Check if token was found in headers
    if (!token) {
      res.json({
        success: false,
        message: 'No token provided'
      }); // Return error
    } else {
      // Verify the token is valid
      jwt.verify(token, config.secret, (err, decoded) => {
        // Check if error is expired or invalid
        if (err) {
          res.json({
            success: false,
            message: 'Token invalid: ' + err
          }); // Return error for token validation
        } else {
          req.decoded = decoded; // Create global variable to use in any request beyond
          next(); // Exit middleware
        }
      });
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without doing too much of a deep dive into your auth headers, I see a pretty glaring issue that I think may be the cause of your troubles.

HTTP REST verbs carry different "intents", the intent we specifically care about in this case is wether or not your request should have a body.

`GET` requests do **not** carry a body with them.

`PUT` requests **do** carry a body.

Because of this, angular's `HttpClient` request methods (`http.get`, `http.post`, etc.) have different method signatures.

To cut to the chase, **`http.put`'s method signature accepts 3 parameters: `url`, `body`, and `options`, whereas `http.get`'s method signature only accepts 2: `url` and `options`.**

If you look at your example, for `http.put` you are providing `this.httpOptions` as the **second** parameter instead of the third, so Angular is packaging up your `options` object as the `PUT` request body. This is why you have a working example and a non-working example; the working example is a `GET`!

The solution? Simply put something else as the request body in the second parameter and shift `this.options` down to the third parameter slot. If you don't care what it is, just use the empty object: `{}`.

So your request should look like this:

```js
return this.http
      .put(this.domain + 'api/appointments/' + id + '/cancel', {}, this.options)
```

At the very least, this should send whatever is in `this.options` to the server correctly. Now wether what's in `this.options` is correct or not is another story.

Example `PUT` call from Angular's docs: https://angular.io/guide/http#making-a-put-request

Comment: That caused the error! Thanks for your explanation, makes sense to me. :)